# when I do this it gives me t(...).map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, i18next

how can I iterate array elements to unrodered list with map

```
"text": ["Tashkent", "Discounts", "Delivery", "Help", "Contact"]
```

```
App.js file
 {t("text", { returnObject: true }).map((text, country_code) => ( {text} ))}
```

when I do this it gives me t(..).map is not a function how ever when I do console.log(t("text", { returnObject: true })) it gives me array.

I don't have any idea about it. could you help me?

Comment: `t` with `returnObject` returns an object, not an array. Objects are not mappable. Try entries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: What does `t("text", { returnObject: true })` return? Can you paste it here?

Comment: in the JSON file I have following code: "text": ["Tashkent", "Discounts", "Delivery", "Help", "Contact"]
}
 And when I do console.log((t("text", {returnObjects: true})) it gives me array on console yet when I am mapping it returns me t(...).map is not a function

Comment: Put your array on console here and you should describe your problem more details so we detect the problem easier